# Dynamic Island Compact Presentation Margin Issue after updating Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetliveactivity, dynamic-island

Previously, the dynamic island had smaller side margins (Screenshot A) which looks apt, however after updating the Xcode the side margins looks too wider (Screenshot B).

I already tried using `.contentMargins(.all, 0, for: .compactLeading)`and `.contentMargins(.all, 0, for: .compactTrailing)`, but it rather end up slicing the icons instead.

[image: Dynamic Island Margin Issue Screenshot ↗]

Thanks!

Comment: Great, and I thought I was the only one with this issue! Xcode 15.0.1 here.